# Using IN clause in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

My query is like below.I want to select values if Type = 1 and subtype = 1,3 or 2.

```
select sum(case when Type = 1 and  SubType in (1, 3 or 2) then 1 else 0 end) as 'WorkStations'
```

Is this right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only trying to get a count of the workstations that meet the criteria as far as I can see:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Workstations FROM MyWorkStationTable WHERE Type = 1 AND SubType IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Also, an IN clause is by nature already an OR. It is neither valid syntax nor necessary to state it.

Comment: Thanks Jamie.I want trying to get this. Workstations [#] – identify by counting Hardware assets set with Sub-Type Workstation, Tablet or Laptop

Comment: Instead `select count(PrimaryKeycolumn)` should be preferred.

Comment: @RGI Good point. Since I have no knowledge of the table schema and to avoid potential confusion, I supplied *.

Comment: @RGI Makes no difference. - `COUNT(*)` vs `COUNT(1)`  vs `COUNT(PK)` all get the same plan.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply counting records, your best bet is to use the COUNT function provided by SQL Server.  Consider using the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE TYPE = 1
                              AND (SUBTYPE = 1
                               OR  SUBTYPE = 2
                               OR  SUBTYPE = 3)
```

It is best to avoid using 'IN' as it can lead to unnecessary calls to the SQL engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) [Workstations] FROM [YourTable] t WHERE t.Type = 1 AND t.SubType IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding `IN` Predicates and instead use Joins because it Iterate unnecessarily despite of the fact that there is just one/two match. I will explain it with an example.

Suppose I have two list objects.

```
List 1      List 2
  1           12
  2            7
  3            8
  4           98
  5            9
  6           10
  7            6
```

Using `IN`, it will search for each **List-1** item in **List-2** that means iteration will happen **49 times** !!!